# Do I need to change web service path everytime when I call it?

Tags: c#, web-services

I am developing on Windows application in c# and I am using web server's web service in this Windows application.

The web service should be dynamic and I need to change it in the application.

I managed to do it by this code :

```
CallWebService.MyWS ws = new CallWebService.MyWS();
ws.Url = "new url";
```

This new url will be set as per client's web server url.

I am calling this web service (I mean web service functions) 20 to 25 times in my application.

Do I need to change this path everytime when I call it or for the first time will be ok ?

Comment: Use a fixed port number for your service and configure this url in your app/web.config file and use it in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed port number for your service and configure this url in your app/web.config file and use it in your code.

Comment: web.config of a web service or an application ?

Comment: web.config of your application, it will hold fixed url for your webservice.

Comment: ohk and everytime when i call the service in my application do i need to set that url ? or i can set it for the first call only?

Comment: Just create a static function which fetches the `WebServiceUrl` key from your application config and returns it.

Comment: @Mausami - Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper class and use that. Make it configurable by using an app setting or better store in config table in database if you are using one.

If you are using WCF client, you can pass URL in client constructor. Otherwise create a partial class for your webservice to create that constructor.

```
public class MyWebServiceHelper
    {
        private string _url = null;

        public MyWebServiceHelper()
        {
            this._url = GetWsUrlFromDbOrAppConfig();
        }

        public CallWebService.MyWS GetMyWebServiceProxy()
        {
            return new CallWebService.MyWS("WcfBindingConfig", _url);
        }
    }
```